# Applying XSLT to WCF message

Tags: .net, xml, wcf

We would like to transform the outgoing XML from a WCF request if certain conditions are met.
Is there a way to intercept the XML stream right before it goes over the wire with WCF?
I found an approach where you use Message objects and override OnWriteBodyContents method, bu in there you have to create XML by hand and ideally we would like a simpler method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build a message inspector and apply the transform in there:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx